# Recommended format for Git commit messages

Tags: git, version-control, formatting, conventions

What is the recommended format for Git commit messages, if there is any?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It varies, of course, but a very common format is something like this (taken from http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html, that I think sums it up really well):

```
Short (50 chars or less) summary of changes

More detailed explanatory text, if necessary.  Wrap it to about 72
characters or so.  In some contexts, the first line is treated as the
subject of an email and the rest of the text as the body.  The blank
line separating the summary from the body is critical (unless you omit
the body entirely); tools like rebase can get confused if you run the
two together.

Further paragraphs come after blank lines.

 - Bullet points are okay, too

 - Typically a hyphen or asterisk is used for the bullet, preceded by a
   single space, with blank lines in between, but conventions vary here
```

One thing it doesn't address is something I've adopted for myself, namely using short tags at the start of the firstt line to identify what kind of commit it is. That might be tags like `[fix]` for a bugfix, `[new]` for a new feature or `[dev]` for a commit that only affects internals. With a policy like that, it's easy to autogenerate a changelog from the commits.

**Edit:** Here's another good summary, from this site even: [In git, what are some good conventions to format multiple comments to a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512177/in-git-what-are-some-good-conventions-to-format-multiple-comments-to-a-single-co)

Comment: The much more common prefix for the first line is the part of the project the commit applies to. It could be a filename, a module, whatever suits you. Otherwise, I think you've pretty much covered the usual suspects!

Comment: I tend to not clutter up my summary with any metadata (other than bug pointers).  Well written commits with good summaries are a good start.  you can always add tags near the bottom of the summary to decide whether something is eligible for release notes.  Then I put those in the actual tag and [generate my changelog](http://dustin.github.com/2009/01/17/changelog.html) from tags.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend large messages. If you can't explain in one sentence what you are doing, your commit encompasses too much change. Use git rebase -i and split up your commit if you already committed. If you have not committed the changes yet, use git add -p to stage in small parts and then commit as smaller commits.

A granular change history like this will help subsequent merges and rebases. It will also help you link to your issue tracker. If you have 2 or more tickets addressed, it will be more difficult to decipher what ticket each change in the commit addressed.

Comment: Nontrivial changes often require substantial explanation, particularly if one is working on a large project that has to preserve the semantics of an external and/or internal specification document.  I've had to write four paragraph commit messages to change a single macro in the MPICH source because I had to explain the MPI standard behavior AND the internal macro semantics to justify the change.  Had I not done this, some future developer would waste an inordinate amount of time rediscovering that information.

I'd downvote if I could...

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff. Software is such a huge world it's really not about rules but rather guidelines. Sometimes it's just not possible to apply them.

Comment: I agree with the idea of atomic commits (which is why a generally dislike squashing) however I feel it's better to error on the side of providing more context than needed rather than less.  Also if the work was not commited as atomic commits I would not recommend breaking them up after as you suggest.  This raises the risk of committing incomplete code.

Answer (score 0):

The commit diff describes a change in the project *text* (syntactic change) whereas the commit message describes a change in the project *meaning* (semantic change).

Commit message format:

- The first line describes the semantic *change* and its scope. It is limited to 50 characters, written in imperative mood, and does not end with a period.
- The next line is empty.
- The remaining lines describe the semantic *context* before and after the semantic change and its limitations. They are wrapped at 72 characters.

Commit message examples:

```
Percent-encode requests_mock URIs in API tests

Before, 32 API tests failed with the default .env file because it 
contains the characters ‘<’ and ‘>’ (used as variable delimiters) which 
are automatically percent-encoded in requests URIs (as those characters 
are not allowed in URIs) but not in requests_mock URIs.

Now, all tests pass with the default .env file.

This does not percent-encode URIs in non-failing tests.
```

```
Add a company selection page in HTML templates

Before, users logged in to different accounts by entering different 
credentials in the login page.

Now, users log in to different accounts by entering the same credentials 
in the login page and selecting different companies in the company 
selection page.

This does not allow logged in users to switch account without logging 
out.
```

References:

- https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#_commit_guidelines
- https://google.github.io/eng-practices/review/developer/cl-descriptions.html
- https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages
- http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-commit-messages.html
- https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html
- https://cbea.ms/git-commit/